# Sessions not being passed to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

I am trying to pass information from one page to another using sessions, the actual sending occurs when clicking a send button like this:

```
       protected void btnContactMsgSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Name = txtName.Text;
        EmailAddress = txtEmailAddress.Text;
        Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        MessageBody = txtMssgBody.Text;


        Session.Add("Name", Name);
        Session.Add("Email", EmailAddress);
        Session.Add("Subject", Subject);
        Session.Add("MessageBody", MessageBody);

        try
        {
            Server.Transfer("~/UserPages/ContactUsConfirm.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBody = Environment.NewLine + "Error occurred" + exc.ToString() ;
        }
    }
```

In the receiving page I do the following:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        string name = null;
        string email = null;
        string subject = null;
        string message = null;

        try
        {
            name = Convert.ToString(Session["Name"]);
            email = Convert.ToString(Session["Email"]);
            subject = Convert.ToString(Session["Subject"]);
            message = Convert.ToString(Session["MessageBody"]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtOutput.Text = Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString(); // edited exception

            name = "Missing name";
            email = "Missing e-mail";
            subject = "Missing subject";
            message = "Missing message";
        }
        txtOutput.Text = Environment.NewLine + name;
        txtOutput.Text = Environment.NewLine + email;
        txtOutput.Text = Environment.NewLine + subject;
        txtOutput.Text = Environment.NewLine + message;

    }
```

It does not work, in the receiving page I do not get any output.

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Just at a glance I see that in `btnContactMsgSend_Click` you are setting the name session variable 4 different times.  This would cause a problem.

Comment: As @paqogomez says, that may be the problem of setting the name in 4 different times. Instead of this, you dont you create a class with these properties and pass that object thru the session?

Comment: So, was it just a copy paste error? or did that fix a problem?

Comment: @paqogomez Hi there, Thank you for the answers, I had just copied and pasted quicklky without paying attention... now I have edited the code above but it does not work either.  I have also tested doing it like  Session["Name"] = Name; Session["Email"] = EmailAddress; ... but it does not work either

Comment: When you say "It  does not work" what do you get? Is there an exception?

Comment: Are you doing anything that would stop session from working? Restricting cookies, or anything like that?

Comment: No, in that page the only thing I have is 4 properties for those values, in the receiving one I have what I pasted above only. And what happens is that there is nothing, not even an exception, I edit the code above to get an exception...

Answer (score 1):

It should be...

```
Session["Name"] = Name;
Session["Email"] = EmailAddress;
Session["Subject"] = Subject;
Session["Message"] = MessageBody;
```

Comment: Thank you ... It was an error in copying and pasting and it was edited in the post but it does not work either... like this.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be originating because of some settings not set for Sessions.

Do you have set `enableSessionState="true"` for the  `pages` tag in  web.config.Also try adding the session to `httpmodules` section:

```
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
```

One more thing to do is try using [**`Context.RewritePath`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Server.Transfer`.

Comment: Thank you much!! Well I guess that is the problem, no I don't have that setup is there any good source to read onto this?

Comment: You can start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @FlopSicentist One more thing..  I have added enableSessionState="true" to the page tag, but when I add the other tag to httpmodules (within the <system.web> tag) I get an internal HTTP Error 500.19. why is that?

Comment: Then if I use the method Context.RewritePath I get a "server error Validation of viewstate MAC failed".

Comment: Query 2: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx |||  Query 1: Error 500 comes when there is some wrong updates done by you in web.config, possibly some tags misformed etc. So check that you made changes to web.config correctly. Check the Last answer of this thread for example on how to make entry in web config: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/655618-how-use-session

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the same names for the session variables. Messagrbody and message are different when setting and getting it.

Comment: Thank you much, yes you are right, but that is only true for the Message, in which case it should have outputted "No message" as it is caught by the exception but it is not happening. I have just edited it but it does not work either, not even with: enableSessionState="true"

Comment: I think session["message"] just gives a null. Then the convert(null) will not fail. Try session["Message body"].tostring(). This will fail with an exception. testing with isnullorempty is a gar nicer solution than catching exceptions

Comment: Hi there and thank you! it is true it now gives me the exception. But still the sessions don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try  adding this line to your `web.config` file inside <system.web>:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false" requireSSL="false"/>
```

Comment: That's not a valid line for a `web.config` file. Can you [edit] your answer to display this as an XML element?